# Some images not showing in Searxng Search engine

Tags: python, nginx, flask, searxng

I am using Searxng as a search engine. I have installed it on digital ocean with a valid domain. Now I am facing the issue that in the result section some of the image is not loading. Can you help me to provide me some code or some settings to correct it please see the attached images. Thanks.
[Screen shorts of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdiPw.png)

I have tried by disabling the image_proxify but it did not worked.